# What's the difference between these two LUA scripts?

Tags: lua, modulo

```
local times=0
function rTA(v)
  times=times+1
  if times % 3 <= 0 then 
        print(v)
    end
end
```

or

```
local times=0
function rTA(v)
  times=times+1
  if times == 3 then 
        print(v)
        times=0
    end
end

rTA("N1")
rTA("N2")
rTA("N3")
rTA("N4")
rTA("N5")
rTA("N6")
rTA("N7")
rTA("N8")
rTA("N9")
```

They both return the same output (N3, N6, N9), but I can't seem to understand the difference in both of them..

Comment: `%` is the arithmetic "modulo" operator. Both scripts are simply checking if `times` is a multiple of 3

Comment: First version would not work correctly after 2^53 invocations :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out both are checking if "times" is multiple of 3, although the first version is a little more "elegant" it costs more in terms of processing. The second is a little less readable in terms of meaning (you can understand that it is trying to check for multiples of 3, but it is not a first sight thing, you have to think for a moment).

Cheers

Comment: "costs more" is true but probably undetectable.